# SharePoint List: squared image thumbnail

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

In my SPO list I can display images contained in the data set. Now depending on the image size (by setting the width to a fixed value) the height differes depending on the image.

Can I display a squared preview of the image by preserving the aspect ratio and "cutting" overlapping parts?
[image]

Like in this preview I try to diplay in list view only the red part.

Showing the full image as a Custom Card is no problem.

Comment: Are you using [Image column type](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) in your list? or anything else?

Comment: Yes, it's an image column.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid we could not "cut" the image as a squared preview of the image using column formatting.

As a workaround, we could make them show as same height with following json:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "img",
   "attributes": {
      "src": "@currentField.serverRelativeUrl",
      "alt": "@currentField.fileName"
   },
   "style": {
      "width": "100%",
      "max-width": "100%"
   }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Thanks for the input. But this works with images with the same aspect ratio like in your picture. When mixing different ratios the height is different.

Comment: What do you mean by "mixing different proportions"? In my test, the three images have different heights and widths.

Comment: Hmm, well all three images are 'landscape', what if the third image was in 'portrait' instead.